# eventRender callback renders all events, how to render only a single event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So I am simply adding an event (created a `json` for it with id, start, etc.)

I tried the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', my_event);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', my_event);
```

These make a callback as following:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    console.log('in event Render callback');
    console.log(event);
}
```

`eventRender` renders all the events in the calendar when adding a single event. So I can see my added event on the calendar immediately, and the 2 console log statements are printed for all events including the new one.

How can I add only this new event (with a new id) on the calendar such that only this new event is rendered (`eventRender` callback for only new event) and not all the events?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. You want all other events removed when you add one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible by default. You can try to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var date = new Date();
      var d = date.getDate();
      var m = date.getMonth();
      var y = date.getFullYear();

      $('#button_id').click(function() {
        var newEvent = {
          title: 'NEW EVENT',
          start: new Date(y, m, d),
          render: true
        };
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, 'stick');
      });

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
          if (event.render) {
            element.addClass('test');
          }
          event.render = false;
        }
      });

    });
```

Code above will add "test" css class to the last added event only. Maybe this will help you somehow.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qjmw0g2/)